# Programming a JN5168-001-Mxx with a USBtinyISP?

Tags: spi, xbee, zigbee, network

I'm researching different ZigBee implementations for a mesh network application.

I like NXP's JN5168-001-Mxx because it is cheaper than XBee (pricing for 200 units) and has a powerful uC.  Mesh Bee seems to be an open source alternative to the JN5168-001-Mxx, but isn't competitive on price.

The biggest downside to the JN5168-001-Mxx is a lack of community support.

I can't find a specific SPI programmer on NXP's website to use with the JN5168-001-Mxx.  My USBtinyISP is (supposedly) a general-purpose SPI programmer.

*Would a USBtinyISP work with the Jennic JN51xx flash programmer ([JN-UG-3007](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/JN-UG-3007.pdf))? If not, what would?*

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am late to answer this, but thought to share the ideas for others who may come across this question.

You can use FTDI FT232RL or any such USB to TTL converter, connect Rx/Tx of one with Tx/Rx of other, pull down pin 3 (SPIMISO), then pull down Reset (Pin 22), then release reset and then release SPIMISO. This sequence would put JN516x in programming mode. Starting the flash process then should transfer the code to your device.
You can write a program to control the serial port of your computer, using which you can control various additional pins of FTDI to create the above mentioned sequence to put JN5168 in programming mode. For example, you can make use of CTS, RTS, DTR or other pins

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

As I understood the JN5168 is programmable with any SPI flash programmer (I plan to use the UartsBee v5, as described for the MeshBee [1]). If SPIMISO is low on device reset, the JN5168 enters programming mode.

[1] http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Mesh_Bee

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using an FTDI USB to TTL converter to program the Mesh Bee, works great. Simply connect it to the UART0 port and pull down SPIMISO like Simon said. Be careful with the voltage, the Mesh Bee only accepts 3.3v.

Comment: what about the reset line?

Answer (score 1):

here is a [JennicModuleProgrammer](https://github.com/ahfong2006/JennicModuleProgrammer) source code will assist to upload firmware to the NXP JN516X using FTDI USB-Serial cable.

Also there is a [Contiki-OS](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/platform/jn516x) source code and tool chain assistance for the NXP JN516X chipsets (JN5168/JN5169)